# how to replace richtextbox.rtf if and only if the whole word match?

Tags: c#, .net

my original replace code is.

```
rtTextArea.Rtf = rtTextArea.Rtf.Replace(oldtext, newtext);
```

but the problem is it replaces all occurence of the words instead of the required word
e.g origianl word :- hello my name is serak and am in israel
replace() -- is with are the whole word chages to  "are serak and am in arereal"

is there anyway i can include a condition or something to match the whole word?
 my working environment C#.

Comment: Use RichTextBox.Find() and SelectionText instead.  Adding the code to identify a word is something you'll have to work on.

Comment: this replace library is so poor, forget about ReplaceOption , it doesnt even have index to sart from as another parameter option.

Comment: `user1250098` the replace functionality is not poor perhaps it's the coder who has a poor outlook on things as well as being able to think outside the box.. try writing some code and using things such as `IndexOf` methods and perhaps the `.Contains()` method there are so many ways to get that to work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx). In this example the `\b` represents a Word Boundary.

```
var regExp = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\bis\b");
rtTextArea.Rtf = regExp.Replace(rtTextArea.Rtf, "are");
```

Comment: hey how about the input text i want to replace the the word "is" to "are". i mean doesnt replace suppose to be like oldtext=>newtext? and the only parametter i see it the wholestring in myrichtextbox and the newtext.

Comment: This code will replace the word 'is' with the word 'are' while leaving 'israel' intact.

Comment: sorry i have no idea about regular ,and i have been reading about the a couple of minuted and they are so interesting now i know where my proble lies `var regExp = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\b"+oldtext+@"\b");
            rtTextArea.Rtf = regExp.Replace(rtTextArea.Rtf, newtext);`

Answer (score 0):

The previous post showed

var regExp = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\b"+oldtext+@"\b"); 
rtTextArea.Rtf = regExp.Replace(rtTextArea.Rtf, newtext);

Which is a little different from the first post. Notice the extra  b  and  @

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using RegEx for this is the correct approach, but just for brevity you could also prepend/append a space to the word you want to replace to ensure it is not a part of another word.

e.g. `wordToReplace = " " + wordToReplace + " ";`